# Keyboard shortcut for "open next search result"?

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse has this great feature of searching text in Workspace(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>), Project, File or Working Set.

The results are displayed neatly in a Search tab/view and when I *double-click* (i.e. **mouse**) a particular line, the file (in which that searched text is found) is open exactly at where the search text is.

Is there a **keyboard** shortcut for that double-click? To open the **next** one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not one keyboard shortcut to perform this action that I know of, but there are two of them that could work in sequence.

1. Go to Window > Prefs > Keys
2. Search for "Show view search"
3. Set some custom keyboard shortcut because the default one is too long to be efficient (I like to use Alt+Shift+S)
4. Perform your search
5. With the search view in focus double-click the first result
6. When you are ready to go to next item, use a keyboard shortcut to show search view again (Alt+Shift+S for me)
7. Then press 'Ctrl+.'
8. This shortcut will display the next result and open a new file is needed.

So with this sequence you can use two keyboard shortcuts (Alt+Shift+S then Ctrl+.) to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the **Eclipse Keyboard Shortcuts** PDF list for v2.1, v3.0, and v3.1 [**HERE**](http://devcheatsheet.com/tag/eclipse/)

Answer (score 0):

@gamerson has the right answer, but for the future I wanted to make sure you are aware of two key meta keyboard shortcuts:

- Ctrl-Shift-L (Command-Shift-L on Mac) - Opens up a searchable list of available shortcuts.
- Ctrl-3 (Command-3 on Mac) - [Quick Access](http://eclipsenuggets.blogspot.com/2007/05/quick-access-ctrl3-is-bliss-are-you-one.html) gives you a searchable, prioritized list of a bunch of stuff - commands, menu items, windows, tabs, etc. It's pretty darn useful.